# Windows batch (.bat) command to modify the date format of a column

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, command-line

I have data streaming in with the date column in this format:

`MM/DD/YYYY H:M:S`

and am trying to change it to:

`YYYY/MM/DD H:M:S`

I would like to do this in a .bat file, if possible.

*Edit, Here's the answer from Endoro* :

`set "mydate=MM/DD/YYYY H:M:S"`

`for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in (txt) do (`

```
set "month=%%i"
set "day=%%j"
set "year=%%k"
set "mytime=%%l"
```

`)
set "newtime=%year%/%month%/%day% %mytime%"`

`echo %newtime%`

Let me add I would like to do this on a comma delimited text file, if that helps.

*Edit:  First two lines of file:*

```
05/20/2013 11:00:28,1,048392,3.17,98%,4.8,13.3,50.7,29.2,29.9,29.2,2

05/20/2013 12:00:22,1,048392,3.17,98%,4.8,13.3,50.4,31.6,36,31.4,3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use a `for /f` loop:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "mydate=MM/DD/YYYY H:M:S"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%mydate%") do (
    set "month=%%i"
    set "day=%%j"
    set "year=%%k"
    set "mytime=%%l"
)
set "newtime=%year%/%month%/%day% %mytime%"
echo %newtime%
```

.. output is:

```
YYYY/MM/DD H:M:S
```

Comment: Would you mind showing how I would use this with a text file, sorry I am new to writing batch commands.  For instance the text file's first column has the date info.

Comment: If you have a text file with the timestamp in the first line/left side you can try this: `for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in (text.txt) do (` (replace this line with the first line of the script).

Comment: I have edited my original to include your response for the text file.  It isn't working though, I should add my data is comma delimited, but the timestamp is all in the first column.

Comment: So add the comma to the delimiters: `"tokens=1-4 delims=,/ "`.

Comment: So you should post the (first lines of your) text file in your answer or at pastebin.

Comment: OK, take this: `for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=,/ " %%i in (file) do if not defined month (` for the first line of the loop. This works here.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "dat1=MM/DD/YYYY h:m:s"
set "dat2=%dat1:~6,4%/%dat1:~0,3%%dat1:~3,2%%dat1:~10%"
echo %dat1% - %dat2%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - based upon Endoro's code and the extra information you provided.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,* delims=/ " %%i in ('type "file.csv"') do (
echo %%k/%%i/%%j %%l
)>"newfile.csv"
```